# Do we have questions to migrate to Language Learning.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

With the new site, [Language Learning.SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/), I'm asking myself whether we have some questions to migrate to there.

1. Do we have some **tags** that can be more or less safely declare offtopic, since it is on-topic there?
2. How can I help marking individual questions to nominate them for migration?
3. What are the technical limitations? I'm aware SE sites discourage migration of **old** questions, but does it apply for newly-created sites?

<s>P.S. LL.SE is still in private beta stage, so not everyone is yet allowed.</s>

Comment: I wonder if it's not the opposite, some of questions there are about studies which should mainly be the purpose of linguistics.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Language Learning Stack Exchange also accepts questions that require answers from studies. In fact, this is an important category of questions on LLSE.

Answer (score 3):

I have the highest rep on Language Learning, so I thought I'd stop by and add a word. I'm not very familiar with this site, but LL is well past 70 days into public beta, so there definitely could be some potential migration that occurs between these two sites. Keep in mind when migrating, however, that LL's scope includes questions about the effectiveness of methods and techniques used to learn languages, and doesn't include questions about specific languages that can't be applied to a broader set of languages.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of question we've had for years (learning/teaching methodology, didactics, etc.), many of them closed due to offtopic, some are still open, and I'm also a big fan of the idea. However, as I see the reaction, the community does not share my views. :)

Comment: @bytebuster If that's the case, I'm sure they would make a valuable contribution to our site :)

Answer (score 1):

The only tag that I see as being eliminable if the language learning site stays alive is second-lang-acquisition. Otherwise, the only relevance I see of the existence of Language Learning is that questions of the type "I'm learning X and I wanna know...", which are already off-topic anyhow, can be migrated.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a number of perfectly legitimate questions about English linguistics "migrated" to Language Learning, simply because those doing the migrating don't know much about linguistics.  Here is the most recent of these migrations, done by @Alenanno: [question posted to linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17749/is-a-structure-with-past-past-perfect-possible).  My suggestion is: Don't migrate.

Comment: Please note the question is specifically about **[languagelearning.se]**, *not* [ell.se]. And I agree with the migration of the one example you gave, because ELL will be a much more helpful and useful site for non-fluent speakers of English, whereas here the answers, even if they don't include much technical jargon (which they probably will), will likely go over the OP's head. Happens on EL&U, too. If you like that question, however, you could re-ask it, framed in a way which invites more formal and technical linguistic answers.